# What is the most simple/elegant way to calculate the length of a number written as text?

Tags: c++, fixed-length-record

Given the maximum possible value, how to simply express the space needed to write such number in decimal form as text ?

The real task: logging process ids (`pid_t`) with fixed length, using gcc on Linux. It'd be good to have a compile time expression to be used in the `std::setw()` iomanipulator.

I have found that *linux/threads.h* header contains a `PID_MAX` value with the maximum pid allocated to a process. So having

```
#define LENGTH(t) sizeof(#t)-1
```

the `LENGTH(PID_MAX)` would be a compile time expression, but unfortunatelly this number is defined in hexa:

```
#define PID_MAX 0x8000
```

My current best solution is a bit oddish

```
static_cast<int>( ::floor( ::log(PID_MAX)/::log(10) + 1 ) );
```

But this is calculated runtime and uses functions from *math.h*

Comment: What's wrong with hexadecimal? 0x8000 is simply 32768 in decimal, if you're considering the number an unsigned integer, or -32768 if it's signed (using the two's complement method of signing).

Comment: What's wrong with using functions from `cmath` (instead of `math.h`)?

Comment: I could not use the stringifier (#) in macro, to get a textual representation. It returned "0x8000" instead of "32768"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do it with a little template meta programming:

```
//NunLength_interal does the actual calculation. 
template <unsigned num>
struct NumLength_internal
{ enum { value = 1 + NumLength_internal<num/10>::value }; };

template <>
struct NumLength_internal<0>
{ enum { value = 0 }; };

//NumLength is a wrapper to handle zero. For zero we want to return
//a length of one as a special case.
template <unsigned num>
struct NumLength
{ enum { value = NumLength_internal<num>::value };};

template <>
struct NumLength<0>
{ enum { value = 1 }; };
```

This should work for anything now. For example:

```
cout << NumLength<0>::value      << endl; // writes: 1
cout << NumLength<5>::value      << endl; // writes: 1
cout << NumLength<10>::value     << endl; // writes: 2
cout << NumLength<123>::value    << endl; // writes: 3
cout << NumLength<0x8000>::value << endl; // writes: 5
```

This is all handled at compile time.

Edit: I added another layer to handle the case when the number passed in is zero.

Comment: Arg, I was just going to post something almost exactly like that!

Comment: While this is totally working, I shudder at the thought of my Preprocesor having to calculate this on some really high number.

Comment: @AndreasT: How high are we talking? 10^5? 10^20?

Comment: @AndreasT: It's the compiler that does the work.  The problem is O( log( N ) ). No issue for even numeric_limits<__int64>::max(), which needs approximately 21 iterations.  Besides, what else has the compiler to do?

Comment: This is nothing, you should see some of stuff in Abrahams' book on the subject: http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/ The compiler won't even flinch for this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get it exactly without invoking logarithms, but you can get an upper bound:

`CHAR_BIT * sizeof(PID_MAX)` will give you an upper bound on the number of bits needed to represent PID_MAX. You can then precompute log(10) = 3.32 and round down to 3. Forget about floor, because integer division will truncate like that anyhow. So

```
#define LENGTH(t) (((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(t)) / 3) + 1)
```

Should give you a compile-time computable upper bound on the number of characters needed to display t in decimal.

Comment: This LENGTH(PID_MAX) would return 11 on a 64 bit OS, which is a bit too wide for 5 chars

Comment: Like I said, upper bound, not exact.

Comment: OK. But the template version is more "elegant"